# Set tick labels for matplotlib Slider widgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive, matplotlib-widget

The [`slider`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html?highlight=slider#matplotlib.widgets.Slider) behavior in matplotlib has changed with recent updates. With the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax_main = plt.axes([0.15, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6])
ax_skal = plt.axes([0.2, 0.18, 0.65, 0.02], facecolor="lightgrey")

s_skal = Slider(ax_skal, 'time scale', 0.5, 2, valinit=1, valfmt='%0.1f')

#ax_skal.xaxis.set_visible(True)
sl_xticks = np.arange(0.6, 2, 0.2)
ax_skal.set_xticks(sl_xticks)

plt.show()
```

we could generate in matplotlib 3.3.1 and earlier a `slider` object with tick labels.
[image]

However, in matplotlib 3.5.1 the tick labels have disappeared.

[image]

The suggestion [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42305217/8881141) to set the `x-axis` to visible does not work, as the `x-axis` attribute `visible` is already `True`, as is the attribute `in_layout`. So, how can we set tick labels for slider objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I spent some time on this problem, I thought I leave the answer here. Turns out the updated slider version hogs the axis space in which it is placed and removes the x- and y-axes with their spine objects from the list of artists used for rendering the layout. So, we have to add the `x-axis` object (or for vertical sliders the `y-axis` object) again to the axis after the creation of the `slider` object:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
ax_main = plt.axes([0.15, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6])
ax_skal = plt.axes([0.2, 0.18, 0.65, 0.02], facecolor="lightgrey")

s_skal = Slider(ax_skal, 'time scale', 0.5, 2, valinit=1, valfmt='%0.1f')

ax_skal.add_artist(ax_skal.xaxis)
sl_xticks = np.arange(0.6, 2, 0.2)
ax_skal.set_xticks(sl_xticks)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]